# How to align columns of two different html tables with different numbers of fields,but some matching

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have two tables that have some corresponding fields, but have different number of columns. I would like the columns with the same header to be aligned in the page, which must be responsive, so I can't assign fixed dimensions.[-> Asp.net form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9USZs.png):
function ShowNote() {

```
        //document.getElementById('lb_messaggio').innerHTML = "";
        dati = buildJson();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: dati,
            url: "../Home.aspx/GetNote",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                alert(xhr.statusText);
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(error);


            },
            success: function (dataXML) {

                var Messaggio;
                var msg = document.getElementById('LblNote');
                msg.innerText = 'NOTE';
                if ((dataXML.d) == "001") {
                    Messaggio = "Nessun record per i filtri impostati";
                    var msg = document.getElementById('LblNote');
                    msg.innerText = "NESSUNA NOTA DA MOSTRARE";
                    return;
                }

                $("#NOTE tr + tr").remove();
                $("#NOTE td + td").remove();

                var xmlDoc;

                xmlDoc = $.parseXML(dataXML.d);


                $(xmlDoc).find("NOTE").each(function () {
                    var RIGA_ORD = $(this).find('RIGA_ORD').text();
                    var ID = $(this).find('NUM_PRATICA_WEB').text();
                    var NUM_PRATICA_WEB = $(this).find('NUM_PRATICA_WEB').text();
                    var DATA_EVENTO = $(this).find('DATA_EVENTO').text();
                    //  var DESCRIZIONE_EVENTO = $(this).find('DESCRIZIONE_EVENTO').text();
                    var DESC_STATO = $(this).find('DESC_STATO').text();
                    var NOTE = $(this).find('NOTE').text();
                    var TIPO_NOTA = $(this).find('TIPO_NOTA').text();
                    var NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE = $(this).find('NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE').text();
                    var LOGIN_NOTE = $(this).find('LOGIN_NOTE').text();

                    var DATA_EVENTO_S = formatDate(DATA_EVENTO);
                    if (DATA_EVENTO != '') {

                        //$('<tr style="dysplay:inline-block;" id=' + ID + '>' +
                        //    '<td style="display:none;">   </td>' +
                        //    '<td style="width: 15%;" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick = getID(' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '); ' + 'id = ' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + ' NUM_PRATICA_WEB > NUM_PRATICA_WEB:</br > ' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '</td > ' +
                        //    /*'<td  onclick = getID(' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '); ' + 'id = ' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + ': NUM_PRATICA_WEB > NUM_PRATICA_WEB:</br > ' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '</td > ' +*/
                        //    '<td style="width: 15%;" id=' + ID + ':DATA_EVENTO + NUM_PRATICA_WEB ><a href="../CessioneQuintoNew/CQS_Note.aspx?npratica=' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '&RIGA_ORD=' + RIGA_ORD + '" style="text-decoration:none;">RISPONDI A NOTA</a></td>' +
                        //    '<td style="width: 14.6%;" id=' + ID + ':DATA_EVENTO >DATA_EVENTO:</br>' + DATA_EVENTO_S + '</td>' +
                        //    '<td style="width: 14%;" id=' + ID + ':DESC_STATO >DESCRIZIONE STATO:</br>' + DESC_STATO + '</td>' +
                        //    '<td style="width: 15%;" id=' + ID + ':NOTE >NOTE:</br>' + NOTE + '</td>' +
                        //    '<td style="width: 15%;" id=' + ID + ':TIPO_NOTA >TIPO NOTA:</br>' + TIPO_NOTA + '</td>' +
                        //    '<td style="width: 15%;" id=' + ID + ':NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE >NOMINATIVO CEDENTE:</br>' + NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE + '</td>' +
                        //    '<td style="width: 15%;" id=' + ID + ':LOGIN_NOTE >LOGIN NOTE:</br>' + LOGIN_NOTE + '</td>' +
                        //    '</tr>').appendTo('#NOTE');

                        $('<tr id=' + ID + '>' +
                            '<td style="display:none;">   </td>' +
                            '<td  onclick = getID(' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '); ' + 'id = ' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + 'NUM_PRATICA_WEB>NUMERO PRATICA WEB:</br > ' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '</td > ' +
                            '<td  id=' + ID + ':DATA_EVENTO + NUM_PRATICA_WEB ><a href="../CessioneQuintoNew/CQS_Note.aspx?npratica=' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '&RIGA_ORD=' + RIGA_ORD + '" style="text-decoration:none;">RISPONDI A NOTA</a></td>' +
                            '<td  id=' + ID + ':DATA_EVENTO >DATA_EVENTO:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</br>' + DATA_EVENTO_S + '</td>' +
                            '<td  id=' + ID + ':DESC_STATO >DESCRIZIONE STATO:</br>' + DESC_STATO + '</td>' +
                            '<td  id=' + ID + ':NOTE >NOTE:</br>' + NOTE + '</td>' +
                            '<td  id=' + ID + ':TIPO_NOTA >TIPO NOTA:</br>' + TIPO_NOTA + '</td>' +
                            '<td  id=' + ID + ':NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE >NOMINATIVO CEDENTE:</br>' + NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE + '</td>' +
                            '<td  id=' + ID + ':LOGIN_NOTE >LOGIN NOTE:</br>' + LOGIN_NOTE + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>').appendTo('#NOTE');




                        //INIZIO FUNZIONE COLORA TR
                        $(function () {
                            $('#NOTE tr').hover(function () {
                                $(this).css('background', 'LightGrey');
                            }, function () {
                                $(this).css('background', 'white');
                            });
                        });
                    };
                    //FINE FUNZIONE COLORA TR

                }); //fine find('NOTE')

            }, //fine success function

            failure: function () {
                alert("Sorry, there is a error!");
            }
        });
    }


    function ShowStati() {

        dati = buildJson();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: dati,
            url: "../Home.aspx/GetStati",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                alert(xhr.statusText);
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(error);
            },

            success: function (dataXML) {
                var Messaggio;
                var msg = document.getElementById('Lblstati');
                if ((dataXML.d) == "001") {
                    Messaggio = "Nessun record per i filtri impostati";
                    msg.innerText = "Nessuno Stato da mostrare";
                    return;
                }

                $("#STATI tr + tr").remove();
                $("#STATI td + td").remove();

                var xmlDoc;


                xmlDoc = $.parseXML(dataXML.d);

                $(xmlDoc).find("STATI").each(function () {

                    var ID = $(this).find('NUM_PRATICA_WEB').text();
                    var NUM_PRATICA_WEB = $(this).find('NUM_PRATICA_WEB').text();
                    var DATA_EVENTO = $(this).find('DATA_EVENTO').text();
                    var DESC_STATO = $(this).find('DESC_STATO').text();
                    var NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE = $(this).find('NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE').text();

                    var DATA_EVENTO_S = formatDate(DATA_EVENTO);


                    //$('<tr  id=' + ID + '>' +
                    //    '<td  style="display:none;">   </td>' +
                    //    '<td  style="width: 6%;transform: translateX(11%);" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick = getID(' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '); ' + 'id = ' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + ' NUM_PRATICA_WEB > NUM_PRATICA_WEB:</br > ' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '</td > ' +
                    //    '<td style="width: 10.9%;">   </td>' +
                    //    //'< td id = ' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + ': NUM_PRATICA_WEB > NUM_PRATICA_WEB:</br > ' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '</td > ' +
                    //    '<td style="width: 9%;"></td>' +
                    //    '<td   style="width: 11.3%;" id=' + ID + 'DATA_EVENTO >DATA_EVENTO:</br>' + DATA_EVENTO_S + '</td>' +
                    //    '<td  style="width: 16.2%;" id=' + ID + 'DESC_STATO >DESCRIZIONE STATO:</br>' + DESC_STATO + '</td>' +
                    //    '<td><span id="my-div"> </span></td>' +
                    //    '<td class="desc" style="width: 13%;transform: translateX(-20%);" id=' + ID + 'NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE>NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE:</br>' + NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE + '</td>' +
                    //    '</tr>').appendTo('#STATI');

                     $('<tr id=' + ID + ' onclick=getID(' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '); >' +
                        '<td  style="display:none;">   </td>' +
                        '<td id = ' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + ': NUM_PRATICA_WEB >NUMERO PRATICA WEB:</br > ' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '</td > ' +
                        '<td style="visibility:hidden;WIDTH:0.5%" id=' + ID + 'NUM_PRATICA_WEB>NUMmZZZZ1111111111</br>' + NUM_PRATICA_WEB + '</td>' +
                        '<td  id=' + ID + ':DATA_EVENTO >DATA EVENTO:</br>'   + DATA_EVENTO_S + '</td>' +
                        '<td id=' + ID + ':DESC_STATO >DESCRIZIONE STATO:</br>' + DESC_STATO + '</td>' +
                        '<td style="visibility:hidden;text-align:left;padding-left:0px;" id=' + ID + ':NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE >NOMINATIVO_CEDENTEZZ1:</br>' + NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE + '</td>' +
                       /* '<td style="visibility:hidden;WIDTH:0.5%" id=' + ID + ':DATA_EVENTO >ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ:</br>' + DATA_EVENTO_S + '</td>' +*/
                     /*   '<td id=' + ID + ':DESC_STATO >DESC_STATO:</br>' + DESC_STATO + '</td>' +*/
                        '<td  id=' + ID + ':NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE >NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE:</br>' + NOMINATIVO_CEDENTE + '</td>' +
                        '<td style="visibility:hidden;WIDTH:1.5%;" id=' + ID + ':DATA_EVENTO >:D</br>' + DATA_EVENTO_S + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>').appendTo('#STATI');

                    //INIZIO FUNZIONE COLORA TR
                    $(function () {
                        $('#STATI tr').hover(function () {
                            $(this).css('background', 'LightGrey');
                        }, function () {
                            $(this).css('background', 'white');
                        });
                    });

                    //FINE FUNZIONE COLORA TR

                }); //fine find('NOTE')

            }, //fine success function

            failure: function () {
                alert("Sorry, there is a error!");
            }
        });
    }
```

HTML PAGE->

```
        <asp:Label ID="LblNote" runat="server" cssClass="lblNote" >NOTE</asp:Label>
        
        <table id="NOTE">   
       
        <%--    <tr><td>NUMERO PRATICA WEB</td><td>DATA EVENTO</td><td>DATA EVENTO</td>td>DESCRIZIONE STATO</td><td>NOTE</td><td>TIPO NOTA</td><td>NOMINATIVO CEDENTE</td><td>LOGIN NOTE</td></tr>--%>
     </table>
```

<%-- 
--%>

```
           <%-- </div>--%>
       <%-- </div>--%>

   
       
        <asp:Label ID="Lblstati" runat="server" cssclass="lblNote">CAMBI DI STATO</asp:Label>

         <table id="STATI">
        <%--  <tr><td>NUMERO PRATICA WEB</td><td>DATA EVENTO</td><td>DESCRIZIONE STATO</td><td>NOMINATIVO CEDENTE</td></tr>--%>
    </table>   
       <%-- </div>
             </div>--%>
     <%--</div>
     </div>
```

Can I solve it by not using frameworks like bootstrap, but only css and html, nor creating a single table? Thanks

Comment: P.S. I manage to align the columns, as in the image, on my screen, but on another screen they are misaligned

Comment: You'll have to do by hand what bootstrap can do for you, so....

Comment: do you have an idea or an example of how to do it?

Comment: You have to do it with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).